# GWT serialization policy file

Tags: gwt-rpc

I have a GWT2.6.1 application. I uses a RPC call. I defined service, serviceAsync, serviceImpl. But I consistently got following errors:

INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: logLevelServlet: ERROR: The serialization policy file '/analytics/E4322B1E292CEFFC5E147EAE677D2BFF.gwt.rpc' was not found; did you forget to include it in this deployment?

com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: logLevelServlet: ERROR: The serialization policy file '/analytics/E4322B1E292CEFFC5E147EAE677D2BFF.gwt.rpc' was not found; did you forget to include it in this deployment?

com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: logLevelServlet: Downloaded serialization policy from http://localhost:9876/policies/E4322B1E292CEFFC5E147EAE677D2BFF.gwt.rpc

EPARecord.java

```
public class EPARecord implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6723643433565890894L;
private String timeStamp;
private String logLevel;
private String event;
private String comment;

public EPARecord(){}

public String getTimeStamp() {
    return timeStamp;
}

public void setTimeStamp(String timeStamp) {
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
}

public String getLogLevel() {
    return logLevel;
}

public void setLogLevel(String logLevel) {
    this.logLevel = logLevel;
}

public String getEvent() {
    return event;
}

public void setEvent(String event) {
    this.event = event;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}
```

}

LogLevelService.java

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("loglevel")
public interface LogLevelService extends RemoteService {
    EPARecord[] getEAPRecords(String level) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

LogLevelServiceAysnc.java

```
public interface LogLevelServiceAsync {
void getEAPRecords(String level, AsyncCallback<EPARecord[]> callback) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

I cleard browser cache, and I clear the project and rebuild it. It always give the same erorr. I suppose EPARecord file has all String attributes and it is serializable. And in remote interface, it transfer array of EPARecord, it shall be ok without customerized implementation of serializable.

Answer (score 1):

i take some problem.you can remove it and run again your app,if you have "inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'" code line into your *.gwt.xml file.

Comment: Some old codes might be cached, that makes problem. I fixed it by recreated application

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I wanted to connect to the local database with the GAE application. When I recreated my applications without GAE the problem disappeared.

Comment: Some old codes might be cached, that makes problem. I fixed it.